# Does apache server need a router to connect?

Tags: internet, ubuntu-11.04, apache-http-server, lamp

I am trying to set up an apache server on Ubuntu 11.04. I am plugged directly into the wall at my apt complex and I do not have a router. I was able to connect it through my roommates router and access the server through port forwarding but I am unable to connect to the server from an external source when it is just plugged into the wall. Does apache need a router to work or is there some mysterious config file that needs to be changed to allow it?

Comment: Does your roommates plug into the same network that you are connecting to when you plug it into the wall, or does his router connect to a cable or DSL modem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer - no. Not so simple answer, would be another question - what is the port in the wall connected to.

I'd try running ifconfig to check if you're connected to router or modem (if you have neither, well.. you just connected to nothing) , and ping a known server to check for connectivity.

if you get a 'local' (192.x.x.x range, 10.x.x.x range), there's a router. If its a global ip address, there's something else wrong.

Comment: I did ifconfig and found that I was on a 192 address. It turns out that when I connected to the wall jack I was connecting to another router that my roomie was also connecting to with his router. I was able to connect to the router and port forward from there and connect. Good Job!